# React - How to expand an element and hide others, on click

Tags: css, reactjs, expand

I'm new to react and fairly new to programming in general.

I'm using react and want a box to expand on click while the 3 other boxes hide simultaneously. Right now I've just gotten it to add a class of 'hidee' (named that way because 'hide' is actually a feature) on click and send an alert.

Wanting the expanded area to be almost full window size as it will house content.. and then would add a nav bar to the top of that. Below is the concept and my current code is in a sandbox below that.

[image: Concept]

Here's my code so far for this component and corresponding css and html. [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8ploorv968)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


// onclick= (this.expand)
//outside of render:
// expand =(e) => {
//   e.target (targets the one they clicked on)
//   hide every other element of the class add a class to e.target to increase width and height
//   add div to top with nav
// }

class AdminPanel extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  expand = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
    debugger;
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].classList.add('hidee');
      //hide everything except the one we clicked on
        //if event.target != elements[i] then add a class of hidee
      //add a class to event.target called expand

      //make a css file and put in hidee and expand classes and put the css in
      //import that css file at the top of this file
    }

    alert('hi');

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div class="box">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6 ">
       <a href="#"/>

       <div class="box-part text-center">
         <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}>
           <img class="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/224/Folder-595b40b85ba036ed117dd27b.svg" alt=" image"/>

         </div>
         <div className="text">
              <span><h2>Thought Archives</h2></span>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div className="col-sm-6 ">
     <a href="#"/>

     <div class="box-part text-center">
      <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}>
       <img class="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/168/Read%20Message-595b40b75ba036ed117d88f5.svg" alt=" image"/>
      </div>
      <div className="text">
                <span><h2>Incoming Requests</h2></span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div className="col-sm-6 ">
         <a href="#"/>
         <div class="box-part text-center">
           <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}>
             <img class="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/375/Create-595b40b75ba036ed117d7bbf.svg" alt=" image"/>

           </div>
           <div className="text">
               <span><h2>Create New</h2></span>
           </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div className="col-sm-6 ">
        <a href="#"/>

        <div class="box-part text-center">
          <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5040-200.png" alt=" image"/>

          </div>
          <div className="text">
               <span><h2>Your Community</h2></span>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>

  </div>
    </div>
</div>
)
  }
}



export default AdminPanel;
```

```css
/* css for AdminPanel.js*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,300,400,600,700');

body{
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

h3{
     font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.box{
    padding:60px 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
}

.box-part{
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:60px 10px;
    margin:30px 0px;
}

.box-part:hover{
    background:#4183D7;
}

.box-part:hover .fa ,
.box-part:hover .title ,
.box-part:hover .text ,
.box-part:hover a{
    color:#FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.text{
    margin:20px 0px;
}

.fa{
     color:#4183D7;
}
/* end css for adminPanel.js*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
 


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the state of the component in the expand function using setState, When the state changes to true, the render method gets the new state.

```
 constructor(){
    super();

     this.expand = this.expand.bind(this);
     this.state = {
       hide: !this.state.hide
     };
  }


  expand = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
       hide: true
    });

    alert('hi');

  }


  { this.state.hide ? 

     <div className="col-sm-6 ">
                <a href="#"/>

                <div class="box-part text-center">
                    <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/168/Read%20Message-595b40b75ba036ed117d88f5.svg" alt=" image"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text">
            <span><h2>Incoming Requests</h2></span>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>



  : null }
```

Comment: This throws an error for me around {this.state.hide ? and I haven't been able to troubleshoot it. Should {this.state.hide ? be above every card?

Comment: Then Set this on div class name title instead of rendering the entire div   { this.state.hide ?  <div class="title" onClick={this.expand}></div> : null }

Comment: I think class declaration in jsx is wrong it should be className.

Comment: Unfortunately can't get this to work. Probably just my inexperience at the moment. Also, I just added an image to the original post so you can see the concept.

Answer (score 1):

if I were your, I'd definitely split the `div`'s with the class of `title` into a separate component and have an initial data with everything each `div` needs.

If you make that, then you just have to loop through your source of data and render the elements your them to be rendered. As a result, you can show/hide the `navbar`.

I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x95r7kwpw) in which you can see how to control the state of your component and render whatever you want accordingly.

> Assume that each `div` is called `card`

Hope that could help!

Comment: What if I wanted to actually put content inside the card, though? The original thought was to have each card essentially expand to take up the whole screen and inside it would be content.  For now, just looking to do card expands into large empty div and header, with nav bar at the top. Right now the cards shuffle but I still don't see how to expand one.

Comment: I added an image to the original post so you can see the concept

Comment: @KellyHook Yes, I see. You have the basic functionality, so adding that won't be hard. So, when you click the `title` you do two things: 1. Hide the other cards. 2. Show the nav section. The easiest you can do is that you keep the clicked card's id as a state and in the `nav` section you display the other cards + extra content(header + content; as you put in the picture). You add the `id` of the card/title in the state, because then in the nav section you can filter out that specific card. Let me know if that's clear.

Comment: @KellyHook were you able to make that happen?

Comment: We've been working on another portion.. still have to come back to this.

Comment: It's confusing for me -- are you able to demo what you mean in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily as below :

```
class AdminPanel extends React.Component {

  state = {
    //Create sections obj in state to maintain your section's class
    sections : {
      thoughtArchives: {
        key: 1,
        class: 'hidee',
        //add extra data if you want for further use
      },
      incomingRequests: {
        key: 2,
        class: 'hidee'
      },
      createNew: {
        key: 3,
        class: 'hidee'
      },
      yourCommunity: {
        key: 4,
        class: 'hidee'
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  expand = (sectionKey) => {
    //get the prevState
    this.setState(prevState => {
      //if key matches with section to expand add expand class or add hidee class
      for (let k in prevState.sections) {
        prevState.sections[k].class = prevState.sections[k].key === sectionKey ? 'expand' : 'hidee'
      }
      //return sections to update state
      return prevState
    })
  }

  render() {
    let {sections} = this.state;
    return (<div className="box">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6 ">
            <a href="#"/>
            <div className="box-part text-center">
              {/* Append expand/hidee class & attach onCLick listener and pass key of section to expand function*/}
              <div className={"title " + sections.thoughtArchives.class} onClick={this.expand.bind(this, sections.thoughtArchives.key)}>
                <img className="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/224/Folder-595b40b85ba036ed117dd27b.svg" alt=" image"/>
              </div>
              <div className="text">
                <span>
                  <h2>Thought Archives</h2>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-sm-6 ">
            <a href="#"/>
            <div className="box-part text-center">
              <div className={"title " + sections.incomingRequests.class} onClick={this.expand.bind(this, sections.incomingRequests.key)}>
                <img className="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/168/Read%20Message-595b40b75ba036ed117d88f5.svg" alt=" image"/>
              </div>
              <div className="text">
                <span>
                  <h2>Incoming Requests</h2>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-sm-6 ">
            <a href="#"/>
            <div className="box-part text-center">
              <div className={"title " + sections.createNew.class} onClick={this.expand.bind(this, sections.createNew.key)}>
                <img className="card-img-top" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/375/Create-595b40b75ba036ed117d7bbf.svg" alt=" image"/>
              </div>
              <div className="text">
                <span>
                  <h2>Create New</h2>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-sm-6 ">
            <a href="#"/>
            <div className="box-part text-center">
              <div className={"title " + sections.yourCommunity.class} onClick={this.expand.bind(this, sections.yourCommunity.key)}>
                <img className="card-img-top" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/5040-200.png" alt=" image"/>
              </div>
              <div className="text">
                <span>
                  <h2>Your Community</h2>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default AdminPanel;
```

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything on click- was it just about adding a class on click? I added an image to the original post of the concept.

Comment: @KellyHook It currently adding class `expand` on box you click and and `hidee` on other box. You can them manage your using that classes.